# Linking CSS file and HTML/PHP files from different folders

Tags: html, css

Hello i have a question about HTML and CSS linking. My problem is that I have HTML files in HTML_folders and CSS files in CSS_folders i want to link my CSS to my HTML but it wont display in explorer. I have linked it as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/index.css">` but no display what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two folders which are siblings (both on the same level in the folder structure) like this:

```
main folder
  |__ HTML
  |__ CSS
```

then to traverse from one to the other you first need to go up and level to the parent and then back down to the CSS folder.

The way you've got it at the moment it's trying to point to a `CSS` folder *below* the HTML folder (i.e. a subfolder of it).

This should work for you (assuming the folder is definitely called `CSS`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/index.css">
```

The `..` is what indicates going up one level.

---

N.B. A more conventional design is usually to have the HTML in a main folder and the CSS in a subfolder (and Javascript in a second subfolder).